# What is the shebang ( #!/bin/bash).

Tags: command-line, scripts, shebang

why do we use shebang in the beginning of a shell script file. does the script will run without it.

I tried running it without shebang in shell script but it didn't run.

Comment: the #! helps the interpreter recognize the code; be it sh, bash, tsch, csh, ksh, .. perl, python .... (*which at times can look alike for short scripts*) [and thus know which interpreter is required to run it]

Answer (score 3):

When a file `script` starts with the *shebang* directive

```
#!langpath args
```

and has execution permissions set, Unix will "replace it" by

```
exec langpath args path-to-the-script.
```

This ways, typically:

- `langpath` defines the language to be used, ans should be the path of an executable interpreter of the (programming) language (ex: '/usr/bin/python')
- the language should accept a script file as an argument
- the language should ignore the `#!...` directive as a comment

Comment: Thank you so much, its really helped me to understand the concept of using shebang.

Comment: @AshishKumarThakur, I am glad it help.

Answer (score 0):

Different shells support different features. To give effective advice, ShellCheck needs to know which shell your script is going to run on. You will get a different numbers of warnings about different things depending on your target shell.

ShellCheck normally determines your target shell from the shebang (having e.g. `#!/bin/sh` as the first line). The shell can also be specified from the CLI with `-s`, e.g. `shellcheck -s sh file`.

If you don't specify shebang nor `-s`, ShellCheck gives this message and proceeds with some default (bash).

Note that this error can not be ignored with a directive. It is not a suggestion to improve your script, but a warning that ShellCheck lacks information it needs to be helpful.